# Display answer of 'Add and Subtract' buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to practice javascript and so I'm trying to do a small javascript code in which a random number is generated whenver the page loads and then the user has the option of subtracting or adding 10 from that number. The user can also input any text in the textfield and the text there will be displayed with the answer. For ex: if the random number generated is 100 and the user choose the 'subtract 10' option and wrote 'Hello' in the text field, the output will be '90Hello'.
I did most of the code, but I can't figure out how to display the answer because it doesn't work for some reason. The random number is shown but the add and subtract buttons are not working. Can someone help with that?

The code till now is:

```js
count = 0;

let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
y = document.getElementById("numb").innerHTML;

function subtractTen() {
  var t1 = document.getElementById("te");
  var n1 = document.getElementById("numb") * 10;
  var subtract = Number(n1.value);
  var ans = subtract + t1;
  var answerSpan = document.getElementById("answer");
  answerSpan.innerHTML = out;
}

function addTen() {
  var t2 = document.getElementById("te");
  var n2 = document.getElementById("numb") / 10;
  var add = Number(n2.value);
  var ans = add + t2;
  var answerSpan = document.getElementById("answer");
  answerSpan.innerHTML = out;
}

function reset() {
  count = countN * 0;
  var res = document.getElementById("numb");
  res.innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Add Subtract</h1>

  <button onClick="subtractTen();" value="sub" /> Subtract 10 </button>
  <button onClick="addTen();" value="add" /> Add 10 </button>
  <button onClick="reset();" value="res" /> Reset </button>
  <br />
  <input name="text" id="te" />
  <span id="numb" id="answer"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `answerSpan.innerHTML = out;` fails because `out` is undefined.

Comment: You have multiple error (next time check the console of your browser), `out` is not define

Comment: Also, `var n1 = document.getElementById("numb") * 10;` is trying to multiply a <span> element by ten?

Comment: Use `valueAsNumber` to get a number value from a text input.

Comment: Also, please add a `var` or `let` to the first line, you are creating a global `count` variable.

Comment: Here's one way to implement this: https://jsfiddle.net/kojudrgs/

Answer (score 0):

```js
//script.js
const container = document.getElementById('answer');
let num = generateRandom(1, 200)
let inputText = '';

function changeText() {
    inputText = document.getElementById('te').value
    container.innerText = inputText + num;
}

function generateRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);

}

function subtractTen() {
    num -= 10;
    container.innerText = inputText+num;
}

function addTen() {
    num += 10;
    container.innerText = inputText+num;
}

function reset() {
    num = generateRandom(1, 200);
    container.innerText = num
    inputText = '';
    document.getElementById('te').value = ''

}

container.innerText = num;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Add Subtract</h1>

    <button onClick="subtractTen()" value="sub" /> Subtract 10 </button>
    <button onClick="addTen()" value="add" /> Add 10 </button>
    <button onClick="reset()" value="res" /> Reset </button>
    <br />
    <input oninput="changeText()" name="text" id="te" />
    <span id="answer"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).